# Cut a large text file in small files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text files which contains 1000000 lines. I want to split it in files that contains 15000 lines each. E.g, first file contains 1 to 15000 lines, next file 15001 to 30000 lines and so on. This is what I have done :

```
lines = open('myfile.txt').readlines()
open('1_15000.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[0:15000])
open('15001_30000.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[15000:30000])
open('30000_45000.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[30000:45000])
open('45000_60000.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[45000:60000])
...
...
... so on till 1000000
```

But this code looks too long. Is there any way I can do this using any loop so that I don't have to wrote separate code for each file?

Comment: *"Is there any way I can do this using any loop"* - yes, of course!

Comment: Python uses *0-based indexing*; unless you want to miss out on the first line, use `lines[0:15000]` or `lines[:15000]`.

Comment: Reading the whole thing into memory and slicing it is silly. Read 15000 lines and write them to a file, then open the next one...

Comment: Yes of course, I mistyped it. That's why I used 15000 in second line and not 15001.

Comment: Make a subprocess that uses `split` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines = open('myfile.txt').readlines()
for i in range(0, 1000000, 15000):
   open('{0}_{1}.txt'.format(i+1, i+15000), 'w').writelines(lines[i:i+15000])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Simple, short and perfect !! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = open('myfile.txt').readlines()
```

loads the entire file into a Python list. You won't want to do this when a file is large since it may cause your machine to run out of memory.

---

This splits the file into chunks of `N` lines. Each chunk is a list. It stops when a chunk is an empty list.

```
import itertools as IT
N = 15000

with open('data', 'rb') as f:
    for i, chunk in enumerate(iter(lambda: list(IT.islice(f, N)), [])):
        outfile = '{:06d}_{:06d}.txt'.format(i*N, (i+1)*N)
        with open(outfile, 'wb') as g:
            g.writelines(chunk)
```

If the file contains `N` empty lines, then the above method may end prematurely. Or if `N` were really large, reading `N` lines into a Python list may cause a MemoryError. You could avoid these problems by handling one line at a time (by calling `next(f)`) and catching the StopIteration exception that signals the end of the file:

```
import itertools as IT
N = 15000

with open('data', 'rb') as f:
    try:
        for i in IT.count():
            outfile = '{:06d}_{:06d}.txt'.format(i*N, (i+1)*N)
            with open(outfile, 'wb') as g:
                for j in range(N):
                    line = next(f)
                    g.write(line)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
lines = open('myfile.txt').readlines()
count = 0
incr = 15000
while count<len(lines):
    open(str(count)+'_'+str(count+incr)+'.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[count:incr])
    count += incr
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also do this with the linux [split](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm) utility. No need to reinvent the wheel!